# Accessing values in JSON response - error generated - json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:100)

Tags: android, json, response

I have the following response:

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "name": "This is a test 123",
         "start_time": "2013-12-02T18:00:00+0530",
         "end_time": "2013-12-02T20:00:00+0530",
         "location": "Mount Lavinia",
         "id": "525447507473743",
         "rsvp_status": "attending"
      },
      {
         "name": "This is a test event",
         "start_time": "2013-12-02T18:00:00+0530",
         "end_time": "2013-12-02T20:00:00+0530",
         "location": "Mount Lavinia",
         "id": "560383743988530",
         "rsvp_status": "attending"
      },
}
```

],

I have the following code to access the response:

```
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(result);
                JSONArray jsonArr = jsonObj.getJSONArray("data");
                for(int i = 0; i < jsonArr .length(); i++)
                {
                   JSONObject jsonArrObj = jsonArr.getJSONObject(i);
                   String id = jsonArrObj.getString("id");
                   String username = jsonArrObj.getString("name");
                   Log.w("event names are", username.toString());

                }
```

I get the following error:

```
json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:100)
```

I searched for a solution but could not get any.

Comment: Which of the lines is giving the error, the first one?

Comment: there are no compile errors, I see "json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:100)" onlin the log cat

Comment: is your response quote complete? It looks like you are missing the `]` at the end of the array. Also a `,` is to much after your second array

Comment: Use an online json validator and check form errors

Comment: sorry, I mistakenly avoided putting ] and , , because there are so many elements, so I put only 2. I pasted the whole response on JSON PARSER ONLINE and it works fine...

Comment: @TharakaNirmana : when you json is valid then what is problem in parsing because you are doing in right way?

Comment: I am looking for the solution, I get this error: json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:100)

Comment: @TharakaNirmana : if you are still facing issue then post your service url i will ty it

Comment: I have just tested your code with your pasted json response. It works fine. So there must be something wrong in the response you did not show us

Comment: @imran url - https://graph.facebook.com/me/events?access_token=AAACEdEose0cBAJor7pnPChf3bEMO45IVHhRMFmWZAnj4G7WHpxi2MyKS0VDfVYZAwn8tXz2rr3vPdHPPo1TIjZACbpMcGFpE9bB0zanqXlSNYRgOL6H

Comment: @zerd - were you able to extract name and id of events and output to logcat? I am still not getting, this is my response: https://graph.facebook.com/me/events?access_token=AAACEdEose0cBAJor7pnPChf3bEMO45IVHhRMFmWZAnj4G7WHpxi2MyKS0VDfVYZAwn8tXz2rr3vPdHPPo1TIjZACbpMcGFpE9bB0zanqXlSNYRgOL6H

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the full parsing of your JSON string you are getting form graph.facebook.com API :

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> arrahaspmap=new 
                              ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
HashMap<String,String> hashmaptemp;
JSONObject jsonObj;
 try {
    jsonObj = new JSONObject(sdskd);
    JSONArray jsonArr = jsonObj.getJSONArray("data");
    System.out.println("jsonArr jsonArr jsonArr jsonArr :: "+jsonArr.length());

    for(int i = 0; i < jsonArr .length(); i++)
         {
           JSONObject jsonArrObj = jsonArr.getJSONObject(i);
           hashmaptemp=new HashMap<String, String>();
           hashmaptemp.put("id", jsonArrObj.getString("id"));
           hashmaptemp.put("end_time", jsonArrObj.getString("end_time"));
           hashmaptemp.put("location", jsonArrObj.getString("location"));
           hashmaptemp.put("name", jsonArrObj.getString("name"));
           hashmaptemp.put("rsvp_status", jsonArrObj.getString("rsvp_status"));
           arrahaspmap.add(hashmaptemp);
        } 
  JSONObject jsonobjpaging= jsonObj.getJSONObject("paging");
  String strprevious=jsonobjpaging.getString("previous");
  String strnext=jsonobjpaging.getString("next");
  System.out.println("jsonobjpaging previous :: "+strprevious);

  System.out.println("strnext next :: "+strnext);
} catch (JSONException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: @Zerd1984 : no need to remove "," it's valid now

Comment: I mistakenly avoided putting ] and , , because there are so many elements, so I put only 2. I pasted the whole response on JSON PARSER ONLINE and it works fine...response seems to be OK, what about accessing them?

Comment: @TharakaNirmana : see my edit answer. this is full parsing of json string and just copy past in your project